# "Virtual" image in WP Media Library (external URL)

Tags: plugins, php, media-library, cdn

We are using a CDN in an external system (DAM) to store all of our images, and I am trying to find a way to integrate this to WordPress.

**The functionality I would like to achieve is:**

- Use the WP Media Library to store image references (i.e. links), but not the images themselves
- Image thumbnails should be pulled from the CDN to display the images
- Extend the "Add Media" dialogue to be able to navigate in the DAM directly, and to select and import media references to images selected.

I found a similar plugin that does this: https://github.com/zzxiang/external-media-without-import

However it seems that this is no longer maintained.
Any ideas how/if this can be achieved or if it's a bad idea altogether?

[image]